# Does using Implicit / Explicit conversion operators violate Single Responsibility Pattern in favor of DRY?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, azure, dry, implicit-conversion

I need to convert between these two classes, and want to maintain DRY but not violate the Single Responsibility Pattern...

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ID {get;set;}
}

public class PersonEntity : TableServiceEntity
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ID {get;set;}

    // Code to set PartitionKey
    // Code to set RowKey
}
```

**More Info**

I have some Model objects in my ASP.NET MVC application.  Since I'm working with Azure storage I see the need to convert to and from the ViewModel object and the AzureTableEntity quite often.

I've normally done this left-hand-right-hand assignment of variables in my controller.

**Q1**

Aside from implicit/explicit conversion, should this code be in the controller`(x)` or the datacontext`(y)`?

```
Person <--> View <--> Controller.ConverPersonHere(x?) <--> StorageContext.ConvertPersonHere(y?) <--> AzurePersonTableEntity
```

**Q2**

Should I do an implicit or explicit conversion?

**Q3**

What object should contain the conversion code?

---

**Update**

I'm also implementing WCF in this project and am not sure how this will affect your recommendation .  Please also see [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092736/if-wcf-is-in-a-mvc-application-should-it-use-the-controller-to-access-the-databa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: The controller.

Q2: Convert manually or with the help of a mapping tool such as AutoMapper.

Q3: I would put the code for this in a converter or mapper class like the following.  Note that IConverter is shared among all converters, and IPersonConverter just exists so your controllers and service locators can use it.

```
public interface IConverter<TModel, TViewModel>
{
    TViewModel MapToView(TModel source);
}

public interface IPersonConverter : IConverter<PersonEntity, Person>
{
}

public class PersonConverter : IPersonConverter
{
    #region IPersonConverter

    public Person MapToView(PersonEntity source)
    {
        return new Person
                   {
                       ID = source.ID,
                       Name = source.Name
                   };

        //or use an AutoMapper implementation
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like a lot more code and classes to write.  Where in your MVC app would you store these classes?  ...what folder?  Do you think it's possible to make automapper make these classes for me as you describe?

Comment: No, the classes are OPTIONAL you could map directly in your controller with my implementation or AutoMapper.  But the advantage of doing it this is the classes wrap the mapping functionality and allow abstraction and separation of concerns, and allow for unit testing etc.

Comment: I'm adding WCF into the mix and am trying to merge his advice with yours.  Mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092736/if-wcf-is-in-a-mvc-application-should-it-use-the-controller-to-access-the-databa

Comment: @makerofthings7 : I have added an answer there