# If WCF is in a MVC application, should it use the controller to access the database to keep 'DRY' 

Tags: wcf, model-view-controller, rest, architecture, dry

I have an MVC application that accesses SQL and Windows Azure.   The logical flow looks like this:

```
Person <--> View <--> Controller.ConvertPersonHere(x) <--> StorageContext.DoDataAction <--> AzurePersonTableEntity
```

ConvertPersonHere is the answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087183/does-using-implicit-explicit-conversion-operators-violate-single-responsibility) and it converts the Model entity to the Storage entity

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ID {get;set;}
}

public class PersonEntity : TableServiceEntity
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ID {get;set;}

    // Code to set PartitionKey
    // Code to set RowKey
}
```

1. Now that I'm adding WCF to the mix, how should I go about accessing data functions?  Assume I have currently have a method to `.Save(Person)` in the controller and want to `Save(Person)` from my WCF call.
2. Do I need to abstract out the data actions in the controller?

Answer (score 3):

I would refactor the code like this - move the functionality to convert from Person to PersonEntity and vice versa to a separate mapper, move saving functionality to separate repository as well, and move controller's code for invoking mapper and repository to separate service too.
So methods in your controller will look similar to:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _personService.Save(person)
        return View("Success");
    }
    return View();
}
```

And in your WCF service you'll be able to reuse the code. In order to validate the classes in WCF using DataAnnotations attributes, you can use the approach similar to the following - http://blog.jorgef.net/2011/01/odata-dataannotations.html

Comment: A couple questions: What does "_personService" look like? Is the "repository" StorageContext in my case? Also I'd be interested in hearing your opinion on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087183/does-using-implicit-explicit-conversion-operators-violate-single-responsibility

Comment: _personService is a service for working with persons. It can be named as Repository too but it depends on implementation. Service for me is a class that works with one or more repositories or/and other services. Repository is a class that just stores, loads, deletes the data from a data storage. And yes, in your case it's a "repository" StorageContext.

Answer (score 2):

From this example, if your Mvc project was gone and replaced by a Wpf project, your other functionality is still available.  If you have both projects they can reference core functionality.  Have the implementation which has no relation to UI (MVC or WPF) in other projects.  This way those UI projects can reference this functionality.

```
public interface IConverter<TDataModel, TModel> { TModel MapToDomain(TDataModel source);}
public interface IPersonConverter : IConverter<PersonEntity, Person> { }
public interface IPersonRepository { Person GetById(int id); }

public class PersonConverter : IPersonConverter
{
    public Person MapToDomain(PersonEntity source)
    {
        return new Person { ID = source.ID, Name = source.Name };
        //or use an AutoMapper implementation   
    }
}

public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private readonly IPersonConverter _personConverter;

    public PersonRepository(IPersonConverter personConverter)
    {
        _personConverter = personConverter;
    }

    public Person GetById(int id)
    {
        PersonEntity personEntity = new PersonEntity(); //get from storage
        return _personConverter.MapToDomain(personEntity);
    }
}

public class MvcController
{
    private readonly IPersonRepository _personRepository;

    public MvcController(PersonRepository personRepository)
    {
        _personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult SomeMethod(int id)
    {
        Person person = _personRepository.GetById(id);

        //make your view model based on the person domain model
        //with another convert / map, to fit view as personForm
        //(if this is overkill you can use person).

        return View(personForm);
    }
}
```

Mvc or Wpf project

- PersonForm (ui model)
- Controller or Wpf Class
- Person -> PersonForm converter
- List item

Core project

- Person
- IPersonRepository

Infrastructure project

- Person Repository
- Person Entity
- Azure Person Table Entity
- Storage Context

Comment: Thank you... where is the "data access layer". I'm told that is where I do my exception handling

Comment: Also should I call the objects in the Infrastructure project a channel [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771818/is-this-a-good-preferable-pattern-to-azure-queue-construction-for-a-t4-template)?  In my mind an Azure queue is of the same level as a Table Entity

Comment: Infrastructure project is the data access layer, having the data access implementation.  As for the channel naming convention I'm not sure.

Comment: If the infrastructure is the DAL should exceptions be managed in repository or storageContext?

Comment: That depends on where the exception is happening and what you want to do with it, up to you to design this.  You could also create your own exception types (maybe in core) and as a result of a caught DAL exception throw those to be caught or to error further down the line...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a tangent, but if you're mixing WCF and ASP.NET MVC, you should at least be aware of [OpenRasta](http://openrasta.org/). A good start is this [Herding Code podcast with the main contributor](http://herdingcode.com/?p=301).

(No, this is not even intended to answer your actual question!)

Comment: I just took a quick look at it... does it support .NET 4 and MVC 3? I don't see any .NET 4 information.  Not sure if it matters

Comment: @makerofthings: It doesnt support MVC3, it supplants it as a way of delivering stuff over http - i.e., deliver a RESTful service/site in a uniform way rather than special casing the service aspects via a wacky contraption like WCF and/or a heavy protocol such as SOAP. I would be extremely surprised if it didnt support .NET 4. I'd be extremely surprised if it'll suit you if your following of the links didnt get you that far though...

Comment: I already exclude *.svc from MVC routing do I won't ignore it yet.  I'd spend more time on it, but I'm busy learning jquery; ScottGu   posted free online classes that end tonight.